# 7 segment with arduino

Tags: arduino-mega

I am getting error with this. It is displaying those segments which are not to be displayed, i.e., 3.141 is dark and other segments are red. And I have checked that the seven segment module I am having is common anode type only.

```c++
#include "SevSeg.h"

SevSeg sevseg; //Initiate a seven segment controller object

void setup() {
    byte numDigits = 4;
    byte digitPins[] = {2, 3, 4, 5};
    byte segmentPins[] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
    sevseg.begin(COMMON_ANODE, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins);
    sevseg.setBrightness(1000);
}

void loop() {
    sevseg.setNumber(3141, 3);
    sevseg.refreshDisplay(); // Must run repeatedly
}
```

Comment: How did you wire the display. Have a schematic?

Comment: What dispatch are you using. Seems like it has  active high hardware on the segments

Comment: its schematic is on website sunrom.com , as it's device of the same company with model number 1188. although its been out dated, but I need solution..

Comment: sunrom.com    model no. 1188

Comment: http://www.sunrom.com/p/4x-7-segment-display-multiplexed

Comment: sevseg.begin(P_TRANSISTORS, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins);

Comment: using this,, it correctly works,,....... Thankyuiiiii

Answer (score 1):

If you use [this library](https://github.com/DeanIsMe/SevSeg), then use

```
sevseg.begin(P_TRANSISTORS, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins);
```

Comment: P_TRANSISTORS because the schematic has PNP transistors?

Comment: @linhartr22 probably, but I just went straight to the source code to see with options had active-low for both the digits and the segments.